# Return child class from overriden method in Inheritance

Tags: c#

I've created a base class as follows:

```
    public class BusStopEvent
    {
        public virtual BusStopEvent CreateEvent(int BusStopNumber) 
        {
            return new BusStopEvent();
        }
    }
```

Child class as

```
public class BusArraival : BusStopEvent
{

    public override BusArraival CreateEvent(int BusStopNumber)
    {
        BusArraival evnt = null;
        evnt = base.CreateEvent(BusStopNumber);
        return evnt;
    }
}
```

I'm getting below error:

**'BusArraival.CreateEvent(int)': return type must be 'BusStopEvent' to match overridden member 'BusStopEvent.CreateEvent(int)'.
Cannot implicitly convert type 'BusTerminal.BusStopEvent' to 'BusTerminal.BusArrival'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

Why it's showing me this error? Since BusArrival is derived from BusStopEvent, the child object should be compatible with Parent object.